# Use many PHP version with LXC

Tags: php, containers, lxc

I need to have this architecture :

[image: Example]

I want to switch between different PHP versions with LXC containers. But I  don't see how to configure.
It is possible ?

Ty

Comment: Take a look at WAMPServer Version 3 http://www.wampserver.com/ If you are a windows user Downloads for V3 are here [on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/)

Comment: I have to use LXC and i'm a Linux user

Comment: Ok ignore my previous comment